# Program searching and visualising all simple paths between two vertices in undirected graph

Tags: windows, graphs

I have undirected weighted labeled graph. What program i can use to generate and visualize tree graph, showing me all simple paths from vertice A to vertice B? //The vertices in each path should not be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

The graph visualization software [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) may be used for that purpose. Graphs specified in the [DOT language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) can be generated to common image formats. With the [`concentrate`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dconcentrate) graph attribute you can specify that multiple edges are merged into one. The vertices (nodes in DOT terminology) are never repeated in the graphs. In case you have a tree graph all paths will be simple paths already.

[Tree definition in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29#Tree):

> Any two vertices in G can be connected by a unique [simple path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)).